# Update Default Curl command in Dev portal of WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

[image]

in wso2 3.0 on dev portal -> go-to application -> generate keys -> click generate curl for token
it shows the above image with localhost how do I change it with the domain of my dev portal or how do i update it to some other value

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to the host name of the Gateway by updating the `https_endpoint` value under `[[apim.gateway.environment]]` in the `deployment.toml`. In this case the host name of the token url will be updated to the host name of the Gateway you define. For more info, check [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-gateway-environment-configurations).

Otherwise, if you have separate key-manager configurations, you can update the `service_url` value under `[apim.key_manager]` config in the `deployment.toml`. For more info, check [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-key-manager-related-configurations). In this case, the host name of the token url will be the host name of the key-manager service

Comment: please try from your end first it does not work, please find comments below

Answer (score 0):

For APIM v320, you can use the following configurations.

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://gw:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://gw:${https.nio.port}"
```

The following configs are used.

1. show_as_token_endpoint_url
2. https_endpoint

The endpoint is derived from the https endpoint and it appends the token context.

Comment: it does not work I have following configurations in my dev-portal toml file but still showing localhost

Comment: http_endpoint = "http://sbxgw.ecosystem-a2.**.fi:80"
https_endpoint = "https://sbxgw.ecosystem-a2.**.fi:443"
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true

Comment: What's your APIM version?

Comment: APM 3.0.0 one more point if my setup is distributed shall i change it in the developer portal toml?

Comment: Yes, you have to do this change in the devportal toml..